# How to use the opencvsharp 3 polylines/fillpoly library function

Tags: c#, opencv

I'm new to openCvSharp and I'm learning OpenCvSharp 3 from vs nuget plug-in.
I was able to draw lines and circles OK. But I'm having trouble with
the drawing polylines/fillPoly function. One of the calling parameters is of the worry type. I think it is the rook_point array. I tried other version (definitions) for passing the array to no avail.

I'm stump. If you can help... please response.

Thanks,
King

```
    using OpenCvSharp;
    class Program 
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create black empty images
            Mat src = Mat.Zeros(400, 400, MatType.CV_8UC3);

            int w = 400;
            /* Create some points */
            Point[] rook_points = new Point[20];

            rook_points[0] = new Point(w / 4.0, 7 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[1] = new Point(3 * w / 4.0, 7 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[2] = new Point(3 * w / 4.0, 13 * w / 16.0);
            rook_points[3] = new Point(11 * w / 16.0, 13 * w / 16.0);
            rook_points[4] = new Point(19 * w / 32.0, 3 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[5] = new Point(3 * w / 4.0, 3 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[6] = new Point(3 * w / 4.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[7] = new Point(26 * w / 40.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[8] = new Point(26 * w / 40.0, w / 4.0);
            rook_points[9] = new Point(22 * w / 40.0, w / 4.0);
            rook_points[10] = new Point(22 * w / 40.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[11] = new Point(18 * w / 40.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[12] = new Point(18 * w / 40.0, w / 4.0);
            rook_points[13] = new Point(14 * w / 40.0, w / 4.0);
            rook_points[14] = new Point(14 * w / 40.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[15] = new Point(w / 4.0, w / 8.0);
            rook_points[16] = new Point(w / 4.0, 3 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[17] = new Point(13 * w / 32.0, 3 * w / 8.0);
            rook_points[18] = new Point(5 * w / 16.0, 13 * w / 16.0);
            rook_points[19] = new Point(w / 4.0, 13 * w / 16.0);

            Cv2.FillPoly(src, rook_points, true, new Scalar(255, 255, 55));  // invalid parameter

            using (new Window("Image", src))
                Cv2.WaitKey(0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the post linked below about FillPoly and Polylines you will see that you need a List of a List of Points in order to call FillPoly.

https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/181

Here is a quick example.

```cs
Mat output = new Mat(new Size(100, 100), MatType.CV_8U, new Scalar(1));
output.SetTo(Scalar.Black);
List<List<Point>> ListOfListOfPoint = new List<List<Point>>();
List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
points.Add(new Point(10, 10));
points.Add(new Point(10, 50));
points.Add(new Point(50, 50));
points.Add(new Point(50, 10));
ListOfListOfPoint.Add(points);
output.FillPoly(ListOfListOfPoint, Scalar.White);
Cv2.ImShow("Window", output);
Cv2.WaitKey();
```